# How to enable CORS for nodejs Express server?

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to use an Ajax request at my front end:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "localhost:3000/send",
    beforeSend:function(){
             $(".loading_msg").hide();
        },
    complete:function(){
             $(".loading_msg").show();
        }
});
```

But when I load the page containing the script I get the following error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:3000/send' from origin
>   'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin
>   requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome,
>   chrome-extension, https.

And

> Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response
>   was received.

I have tried a lot of things like adding a middleware to express like:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
     next();
   });
```

Which made no difference.

I also tried installing cors npm package and did

```
const cors=require('cors')
app.use(cors())
app.options('*', cors());
```

This made no difference either.

I also tried to change the ajax URL by adding https://

```
 url: "https://localhost:3000/send",
```

While this does remove the CORS error, it gives me another error:

> GET https://localhost:3000/send net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

How does sent an Ajax request from Nodejs express server while using a localhost?

Comment: it matters where you put the line `app.use(cors())`. Make sure you make that call before mounting any of your routes

Comment: Please check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55320833/how-to-enable-cors-for-nodejs-express-server

Comment: @miyu The `app.use(cors())` is above all my routes. @Ashok You are linking to my own question.

Comment: @miyu Thank you! That was my exact problem, I had those two lines in the wrong order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cors error message clearly says you need to use http when making the request

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/send",
    beforeSend:function(){
             $(".loading_msg").hide();
        },
    complete:function(){
             $(".loading_msg").show();
        }
});
```

Comment: what is the point of code snippet when you can't run the code. also if you read the question properly, op has tried using http also

Comment: not writing anything wont ensure its an http it can be anything TLS/SSL, FTP, HTTP,SMTP etc cors need to know when making OPTIONS request.@vikrant

Comment: ah I get it. i was mixing it with origin url.

Comment: I don't really understand why https does not work but http works but I will take it. Thanks

Comment: @jedu are you starting your server on https? using https module? then only it will work with https.

Answer (score 0):

You will need this popular package, [CORS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors).
Another workaround is to add backend to your webapp, using express server and use [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)/[request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) npm package to request data from API server using http, then you won't face any CORS issue.